# Seaport smart contract signature

Tags: solidity, opensea

I created smart contract to buy NFT with Seaport and i use signature from seaport-js but I have an error like this:

[image]

If I convert data to readable error I get this: 'InvalidSignature()'.
Does anyone know how to create a signature with order using EIP-712?

Comment: Please [don’t post images of code, error messages, or other textual data.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/320052/why-are-images-of-text-code-and-mathematical-expressions-discouraged)

Comment: Can you share the code that causes the error?

Comment: yes this is my repo: https://github.com/jecombe/Nfts_trade i used openseaJs to fetch orderParams including signature and pass it to my smart contract

Comment: i test with openSea UI and i have the same signature when i used openSeaJs, but when i pass signature to my smart contract generate error invalidSignature